# Jersey/JAXB bind different JSON format to a single type of java object

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

Suppose I have 2 different types of JSON defined below and I need to map both them to the same type of Java object.

Type **A**

```
{
"startDate": "2013-05-10",
"endDate": "2013-05-19",
"value": "1.5"
}
```

Type **B**

```
{
"startDate": "2013-05-10",
"endDate": "2013-05-19",
"data": "1.5"
}
```

I want to use Jersey/Jackson to map both of them to a single Java class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataPoint{

    public String startDate;
    public String endDate;
    public String value; //What do I do here???
}
```

Essentially `data` and `value` should be considered as equivalent. The conversion to DataPoint is done automatically right now using Jersey/Jackson, how do I customize for this use case?
I am using the Jersey client APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have 2 setters in your POJO which maps from JSON.

```
public class TestPojo
{
  String startDate;
  String endDate;
  String content;
 //Default Constructor.
 //Getter and Setter for startDate and endDate


    public void setValue(String content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public void setData(String content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }  

 }
```

My Test:

```
        String s = "{\"startDate\": \"2013-05-10\",\"endDate\": \"2013-05-19\",\"value\": \"value1.5\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        TestPojo pojo = mapper.readValue(s, TestPojo.class);
        System.out.println(pojo);
        s = "{\"startDate\": \"2013-05-10\",\"endDate\": \"2013-05-19\",\"data\": \"data1.5\"}";

        mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        pojo = mapper.readValue(s, TestPojo.class);
        System.out.println(pojo);
```

Output:

```
TestPojo [startDate=2013-05-10, endDate=2013-05-19, content=value1.5]
TestPojo [startDate=2013-05-10, endDate=2013-05-19, content=data1.5]
```